# Accessing the type of a ReturnType value

Tags: typescript

I want to access the type of the value of a returntype of a function.

I can use this code to get the type, but it is not "clean" by any means, since it creates the unused variable ftype to be able to read the values.

```
const f = () => ({ a: 'a', b: 0 });
let ftype: ReturnType<typeof f>;
let atype: typeof ftype.a;
let btype: typeof ftype.b;
```

is there a proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) :

```
ReturnType<typeof f>['a']; // string
ReturnType<typeof f>['b']; // number
```